# Windows 8.1 application and Top vs. Bottom edge gestures

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, touch

I'm implementing windows 8.1. application and I'd like to show some menus on edge gestures. On top edge gesture Menu A and on bottom gesture Menu B. I found out that it is probably not possible.

In following code

```
void EdgeGesture_Completed(object sender, EdgeGestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Kind == EdgeGestureKind.Touch)
    {
        Scenario1OutputText.Text = "Invoked with touch.";
    }
    else if (e.Kind == EdgeGestureKind.Keyboard)
    {
        Scenario1OutputText.Text = "Invoked with keyboard.";
    }
    else if (e.Kind == EdgeGestureKind.Mouse)
    {
        Scenario1OutputText.Text = "Invoked with right-click.";
    }
}
```

we have possible to recognize if top/bottom menu is invoked by Touch, Keyboard or Right click but EdgeGestureEventArgs doesn't contain any other info.

Do you have any idea how to recognize edge gestures? I mean, if it is Top or Bottom edge gesture.

Comment: Can you see/handle other touch events after the edgie event? Perhaps you could ignore the event when it's coming from touch, but handle the first touch event after it that would be either closer to the top or bottom edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard behaviour is to show both the top and the bottom together. If you use the built-in AppBar control then you'll get this automatically.

If you want to separate the top and bottom app bars then it's trickier and you'll need to implement that yourself. There isn't any direct way to tell if edgie was triggered from the top or the bottom, but you can track PointerEvents and if the EdgeGestureKind isTouch then you can guess based on the pointer location.

There is no difference if edgie was triggered by keyboard or mouse since those gestures aren't location dependant.

Also note that the standard appbar and charms behaviour is different in the Windows 10 Technical Preview than on Windows 8.1, so if you implement it yourself your app's behaviour may end up farther from standard than you intend.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Probably I'll use only TopAppBar and bottom app bar I'll implement myself and showing will be triggered by some another gesture or event from application. This behaviour about showing both TopAppBar and BottomAppBar is really strange and disappointing for me.